# Change values of internal dictionary via attributes

Tags: python, attributes

I have a class where the constructor takes a dictionary. One of the values in the dictionary is another dictionary. I set each of the keys in this last dictionary as an attribute to my class.

```
class MyType(object):
    def __init__(self, d):
            self.__d = d
            for k,v in self.__d['Options'].items():
                setattr(self, k, v)
    def __GetName(self):
        return self.__d['Name'] 
    Name = property(__GetName, None, None, "The name of my type")
    def __GetOptions(self):
        return self.__d['Options']
    Options = property(__GetOptions, None, None, "The options of my type")

myType = MyType({'Name': "Summary", 'Options': {'Minimum': 5, 'Treshold': 7}})
```

I would like to be able to change the values in the Options dictionary through the attribute with the same name:

```
myType.Minimum = 13

print myType.Options['Minimum'] # returns 5, I would like to see here 13
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def __setattr__(self,name,value):
    self.__dict__[name] = value
    self.__dict__['_MyType__d']['Options'][name] = value
```

redefyning the __setattr__ of class MyType. 
I checked that

```
print myType.Options['Minimum']
print myType.Minimum
```

correctly print 13 (both).

edit: added reference http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access

Answer (score 0):

Just try

myType.Options['Minimum'] = 13